# Discord.py making a queue command

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I am in the process of making a discord.py music bot (my first) and am wondering how to make a queue. I'm guessing that it has something to do with the `asyncio` command (`import asyncio`) but I really don't know.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=">help"))
    print("Bot is online! Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'**Pong!** Latency: {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['j'])
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await voice.disconnect()

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['l'])
async def leave(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        print("Bot was told to leave voice channel, but was not in one.")
        await ctx.send("OneBeat is not connected to a voice channel. Connect OneBeat to a voice channel before using this command.")


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await voice.disconnect()

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            print("Removed old song file.")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Trying to delete song file, but it's being played")
        await ctx.send("Error: Music is already playing (Queue feature coming soon).")
        return
    await ctx.send("One second...")

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: print("Song done!"))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.5

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {nname[0]}")
    print("Playing\n")

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Take a look at [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really! I have no idea how to use asyncio and I still managed to make queues. My way of doing it is to have a json file that contains dictionaries and lists. Which looks something like this:

```json
{
    "queueskey": [
        {
            "channelid": [],
            "queue": [],
            "status": []
        },
        {
            "channelid": [],
            "queue": [],
            "status": []
        },
        {
            "channelid": [],
            "queue": [],
            "status": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Something like that repeating over and over again. You can also have extra info stored as well with that. Though it took me quite some time to debug and make the thing work, I'd say this is one of the simplest ways of doing it.